# How to get stable output for torch.nn.Transformer

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, transformer-model

Looks like Transformer layers of pytorch give not reproducible outputs. It happens both for cpu and gpu. I know that it sometimes happens because of parallel computations on gpu.

```
emb = nn.Embedding(10, 12).to(device)
inp1 = torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).to(device)
inp1 = emb(inp1).reshape(inp1.shape[0], 1, 12) #S N E

encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=12, nhead=4)
transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=4)

out1 = transformer_encoder(inp1)
out2 = transformer_encoder(inp1)
```

out1 and out2 are different. It can be multiprocessing on cpu, but results looks too shaky. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nn.TransformerEncoderLayer` has a default dropout rate of `0.1`. The indices to be dropped will be randomized in every iteration when the model is in training mode.

If you want to train the model with dropout, just ignore this behavior in training and call `model.eval()` in testing.

If you want to disable such random behavior in training, set `dropout=0` like so

```py
nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=12, nhead=4, dropout=0)
```

Full testing script:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

device = 'cpu'

emb = nn.Embedding(10, 12).to(device)
inp1 = torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).to(device)
inp1 = emb(inp1).reshape(inp1.shape[0], 1, 12) #S N E

encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=12, nhead=4, dropout=0).to(device)
transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_layers=4).to(device)

out1 = transformer_encoder(inp1)
out2 = transformer_encoder(inp1)

print((out1-out2).norm())
```